How to calculate Borel subgroups of an algebraic group over an algebraically closed field?
Let $G$ be an algebraic group defined over an algebraically closed field $k$. A Borel subgroup of $G$ is by definition a connected solvable subgroup of $G$, which is maximal with respect to the properties.
If we take the algebraic group $G=GL_n$, we have the group of upper triangular matrices $T_n(k)\subseteq GL_n(k)$, which is connected and solvable. It is closed as well. To show that it is maximal we let $GL_n(k)$ act on $\mathbb{P}^{n-1}(k)$ and by induction prove that $T_n(k)$ is the isotropy group of some point in $\mathbb{P}^{n-1}(k)$. This shows that $GL_n/T_n(k)$ is complete, hence $T_n(k)$ is parabolic. Furthermore if any closed connected subgroup $H\subseteq G$ contains $T_n$ properly, then it has to be non-solvable. This proves that $T_n(k)$ is a Borel subgroup of $GL_n(k)$.
Now let us concentrate on the Orthogonal group $O_n$. The definition depends on the choice of the bilinear form. Suppose I choose the bilinear form presented by the identity matrix. Then
\begin{align*}
O_n(k)=\{A\in GL_n(K):~^tAA=I_n\},
\end{align*}
where $I_n$ is the identity matrix of size $n\times n$. Now suppose I want to calculate a Borel subgroup of $O_n(k)$, call it to be $B$. It is very tempting to assume that $B:=O_n\cap T_n(k)$ is a Borel subgroup of $O_n$. Turns out that $O_n\cap T_n$ consists only of diagonal matrices satisfying $A^2=I_n$, as inverse of an upper triangular matrix is an upper triangular matrix.
Now, on searching several references I found out that when we choose the bilinear form to be presented by the matrix $\mathrm{antidiag}(1,\ldots, 1)$, the Borel subgroup of the corresponding Orthognal group is $O_n\cap T_n(k)$. Same applies for the symplectic group as well.
Here is my question: What is the reason behind this phenomenon? By that I mean the following;

How does the bilinear form come into picture? (Well, more precisely why does choosing $\mathrm{antidiag}(1,\ldots,1)$ as the bilinear form give the Borel subgroup of $O_n$ to be $O_n\cap T_n(k)$?)

If given with two (equivalent, but differently presented; for example the symplectic forms given by $\oplus^n \begin{pmatrix} 0&1\\-1&0\end{pmatrix}$ and $\begin{pmatrix}0_{n\times n}&\mathrm{antidiag}(1,\ldots,1)\\ \mathrm{antidiag}(-1,\ldots,-1)&0_{n\times n}\end{pmatrix}$) bilinear forms, can they have the same Borel subgroup (as set)?


If there is any reference explaining this I am up for reading that as well (I am not aware of scheme theoretic language, if at all needed), please let me know. Thank you for your help.

How much do you know about the quadratic forms over $k$? No need to know an awful lot, but anyway. Using $AA^t=I_n$ as the defining equation of the orthogonal group amounts to using the familiar quadratic form $Q(\vec{x})=\sum_{i=1}^n x_i^2$ as the preserved one. That is, we require $Q(A\vec{x})=Q(\vec{x})$ to hold for all $\vec{x}$.. Or, we want the bilinear form $\langle\vec{x},\vec{y}\rangle=\sum_ix_iy_i$ to be preserved. It turns out that over an algebraically closed field it doesn't matter much, which non-degenerate bilinear form is used.

(cont'd) Do you know what a change of a basis (by a matrix $P$) does to a quadratic form (or the bilinear form)? It turns out a suitable change of basis takes that "natural" bilinear form to the one based on the antidiagonal matrix (complication in characteristic two, and you may want to ignore that for now). Anyway, the point turns out to be that only when using the antidiagonal form you get a maximal torus of diagonal matrices and also a Borel subgroup of triangular matrices. Working this out is a useful exercise. I recall spending a full day, if not longer, when I was studying this!

(cont'd) Have fun with it. It is worth your while to work all this out. Oh, and if you change the quadratic form by $P$, you end up conjugating the entire orthogonal group by $P$ also. So you need to conjugate the usual orthogonal group by this suitable $P$ to get one with a diagonal torus and an uppertriangular Borel.

By the way, I would denote the torus by $T$ and a Borel by $B$, but suit yourself!

@JyrkiLahtonen Thank you so much for taking time to explain this. I will summarize what all I (vaguely!) understand about bilinear forms! Over algebraically closed field, of characteristic different from 2, the nondegenerate symmetric bilinear forms are equivalent (i.e. if $B_1$ and $B_2$ are two matrices representing two bilinear forms, there is a matrix $C$ such that $~^tCB_1C=B_2$). As a consequence, two orthognal groups (or symplectic group), arising from two equivalent non-degenerate quadratic (alternating) forms are conjugate to each other in ambient $GL_n$.

@JyrkiLahtonen by the second comment, do you mean that "we want the torus to be consisting of diagonal matrices, and that's why we are choosing the bilinear form to be anti-diagonal"?

@JyrkiLahtonen can there be any other representation of the quadratic form other than $\mathrm{antidiag}(1,\ldots,1)$, for which the torus will be the diagonal matrices, and the Borel subgroup will be consisting of upper-triangular matrices? Thanks again.

I'm not sure (I might answer, if this were all fresh in my mind). With the antidiagonal way you get matrices of the form
$$\mathrm{diag}(z_1,z_2,z_3,\ldots,z_n,z_n^{-1},z_{n-1}^{-1},\ldots,z_2^{-1},z_1^{-1})$$ in the group, and it then goes from there. Weyl group from the normalizer of the torus et cetera.
